# $\hom(K^i,V)\to \hom(K^n,V),$$ $$f\mapsto ((a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mapsto f(a_1,\ldots,a_i))$

Tags: linear-algebra

Describe the Kernel and the Image of the linear transformation
$$\hom(K^i,V)\to \hom(K^n,V),$$ $$f\mapsto ((a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mapsto f(a_1,\ldots,a_i))$$
for the K-Vector-Space $V$ and $i\le n$.

Does anybody know the answer, I have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried ?

Let $\varphi$ be your linear transformation.
For the kernel, you have to describe the $f\in \hom(K^i,V)$ such that $\varphi(f)=0$ (the constant function always equalt to $0$).

For the image, think about the restriction imposed on $g$ if $g=\varphi(f)$ for some $f$.